# Вложенный массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Как создать массив вида:

```html
["item1["subitem1", "subitem2"]", "item2["subitem1", "subitem2"]"]
```

На js такое возможно? Если нет, то есть альтернатива?
Я попробовал использовать объекты со вложенными массивами, но не смог разобраться как их в таком случае заполнять:

```js
$("#go").on("click", function() {
  var obj = {
    clients: [{}, {}]
  }
  $(".test").children(".n1").children(".name").each(function() {
    obj.clients[0].name = $(this).text();
  })
  alert(obj.clients[0].name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="n1">
    <h4 class="name">Name1</h4>
    <input class="n2" value="123" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="n1">
    <h4 class="name">Name2</h4>
    <input class="n2" value="321" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="go">go</button>
```

Пример результата:

```
{"name":["Name1", "123"], "name":["Name2", "321"]}
```

Comment: что должно получиться?

Comment: @Igor, на странице есть определенные поля из которых я беру значение. Мне нужно записать это значение во что-то на подобие массива в ввиде: ["item1["subitem1", "subitem2"]", "item2["subitem1", "subitem2"]"], т.е. есть главный элемент условно name, у которого есть подэлементы phone, email, как это реализовать?

Comment: `{"item1":["subitem1", "subitem2"], "item2":["subitem1", "subitem2"]}`

Comment: @Grundy как такое генерировать динамически?

Comment: @aSpectro, бежать в цикле по нужным элементам и добавлять. Добавь в вопрос  пример результата, который ты хочешь получить для предоставленной разметки.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил, в простом массиве используют push, а тут как?

Comment: `{"name":["Name1", "123"], "name":["Name2", "321"]}` так не получится - в объекте имена ключей уникальны, а здесь дважды используется `name`.

Comment: @Grundy а ввиде `{"names":[{ name: "Name1", val: 123},{ name: "Name2", val: 321},]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  clients: []
};

$("#go").click(function() {
  var name = $('#name').val();

  obj.clients.push({
    name
  });

  alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <div class="n1">
    <h4 class="name">Name1</h4>
    <input id="name" value="123" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="go">go</button>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @aSpectro, а ты пробовал применять этот код к твоей разметке? где несколько n1 и нет id=name?

Comment: @Grundy, я его немного дописал, используя перебор селекторов

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), чтобы пройтись по всем элементам `n1` и получить объект с нужными полями.

Далее с помощью метода [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) получить обычный массив.

Пример:

```js
// {"names":[{ name: "Name1", val: 123},{ name: "Name2", val: 321},]}
$("#go").on("click", function() {
  var names = $(".test .n1").map((i, el) => ({
    name: $(el).find('.name').text(),
    val: $(el).find('.n2').val()
  })).toArray();
  console.log({
    names
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="n1">
    <h4 class="name">Name1</h4>
    <input class="n2" value="123" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="n1">
    <h4 class="name">Name2</h4>
    <input class="n2" value="321" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="go">go</button>
```